# Nose Bleeds at night

Tags: night-time

My son has been waking up with nose bleeds that past couple of nights. Tonight the nose bleed was bad enough it woke my son up.

Is there a way to help prevent nighttime nose bleeds or reduce how often they occur?

Comment: Not being a doctor, I'd suggest making sure the room is properly humidified. But yea, go talk to your doctor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My daughter has the same problem, and a humidifier in her room helped resolve some of it.

We did take her to the doctor but she basically said to keep her fingers our of her nose, which has been a challenge.

Without other symptoms like a fever or earaches there isn't really anything that can be done medically. If it persists for more then 3 days then take the child to the doctor.

Answer (score 5):

A humidifier helps, but even more effective than that is to apply Vaseline to the nostrils using a Q-tip.  Do it every night before going to bed, and hope that eventually he will grow out of it.

Comment: I have allergies that actually dry my nose out!  Go figure?!? and get bloody noses - this is the only thing that has ever worked for me so I do this every fall when I'm most likely to have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have 5 kids, my oldest is 14 my youngest is 4 years old, and every time they woke up with a nose bleed I knew that there air ways were  dry. The results of the allergy treatment Exedra.

I give them saline spray or drops: it moisturizes and flushes out mucus to clean little noses and it has not the side effects of drops or sprays with alcohol.

Answer (score 0):

An older person that I'm quite close had this problem but in a very severe way. Not just in middle of the night. It could be just talking to me or sitting reading nothing extraneous and he used to bleed. He went to the doctor. The doctor told him it could come if you don't drink enough liquids. For this person he told to drink in the morning four glasses of water. He drinks it religiously everyday and gradually it stopped. Maybe this could help you.